# EL1004E: Method call: Method isPermitted(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type MethodSecurityExpressionRoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

Hi everyone I have the following problem when I run my project on Intellij everything works fine but when i make the build using maven install and run my project appears this issue.

[Failed to evaluate expression 'isAuthenticated()

&& isPermitted('domain:read:*')'][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkaY6.png

my code

```
 @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() && isPermitted('domain:read:*')")
    @GetMapping(produces = [(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)])
    fun search(query: DomainQuery): ResponseEntity<ArpiaPage<DomainOutput>> {
        val retval = service.search(query)
        return ResponseEntity(
                retval.map { domain -> converter.convert(domain, DomainOutput::class.java) },
                HttpStatus.OK
        )
    }
    @Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
class ShiroMethoSecurityConfig : GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration() {
    override fun createExpressionHandler(): MethodSecurityExpressionHandler {
        return ShiroMethodSecurityExpressionHandler()
    }
}




   class ShiroMethodSecurityExpressionHandler : DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
    private val trustResolver = AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl()

    override fun createSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication: Authentication, invocation: MethodInvocation): MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {
        return ShiroMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication).apply {
            setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator)
            setTrustResolver(trustResolver)
            setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy)
        }
    }
}

open class ShiroMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication: Authentication) : SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication), MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {
    private var filterObject: Any? = null
    private var returnObject: Any? = null
    private var target: Any? = null

    private val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShiroMethodSecurityExpressionRoot::class.java)

    override fun setFilterObject(filterObject: Any) {
        this.filterObject = filterObject
    }

    override fun getFilterObject(): Any? {
        return filterObject
    }

    override fun setReturnObject(returnObject: Any) {
        this.returnObject = returnObject
    }

    override fun getReturnObject(): Any? {
        return returnObject
    }

    /**
     * Sets the "this" property for use in expressions. Typically this will be the "this"
     * property of the `JoinPoint` representing the method invocation which is being
     * protected.
     *
     * @param target the target object on which the method in is being invoked.
     */
    fun setThis(target: Any) {
        this.target = target
    }

    override fun getThis(): Any? {
        return target
    }


    @Bean
    open fun isPermitted(permission: String?): Boolean {
        return true
    }


    @Bean
    fun isPermitted(vararg permissions: String): Boolean {
        return try {
            val permissionObjects = permissions.map { permission -> WildcardPermission(permission) }

            val user = this.principal as AuthAccount

            //true
            permissionObjects.all {
                user.permissions.any { permission ->

                    permission.implies(it)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            LOG.debug("", e)
            throw (e)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: The obvious cause is that it's using a different version of one or more of the Spring libraries.  How are you running the project?  Are the dependencies compiled into the jar/war — if not, where is it getting them from?

Comment: Thanks for reply, the dependencies compiled into jar and a run my project with java -jar, I am using spring boot 2.3.3

Comment: furthermore if I run the command mvn spring-boot:run everything is ok but I run mvn package or mvn install and then java -jar mybundle.jar the aplication throw the error

Answer (score 0):

Try to use text 'and' in the place of logical operator '&&'. I believe in @PreAuthorize annotation, you need to give text to combine multiple checks

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work, the problem happens when a create the bundle if i run my application in intellij everything is ok but when i create my bundle with the following command mvn clean install and run my application with java -jar my_bundle.jar immediately the error appears